# How to get PHP reference variable in session_decode result

Tags: php, session

I noticed that the PHP session_decode() function has an object type for PHP reference variables signified by 'R'. However, I can't seem to find out how to get session_decode() to output this object type. If I assign a reference variable to $_SESSION, and then call session_decode(), the reference variable is represented by session_decode() as having the same object type as the variable it references and not 'R'. What is the use case for the session_decode object type of 'R'?

Comment: The format produced is IIRC undocumented.  So you can try reverse-engineering the format, but don't be surprised if you run into weird or ambiguous behavior.  I'd suggest checking out the C sources as a starting point...  Oh, and `R` is likely "resource" and not reference...

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-decode.php#56106 it's reference not resource

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For `session_encode` to encode a variable as a reference, the referenced variable needs to be in session too. If it's not in session, then it will encode it as the original type.

```
$foo = 'bar';
$_SESSION['foo'] = $foo;
$_SESSION['bar'] = &$_SESSION['foo'];
$_SESSION['baz'] = &$foo;
$_SESSION['hey'] = &$foo;
var_dump(session_encode());
```

Outputs:

```
foo|s:3:"bar";bar|R:1;baz|s:3:"bar";hey|R:2;
```

As you can see, `foo` has been stored as a string. `bar` has been stored as a reference to `foo`, but since `baz` refers to a local variable `$foo` which may not exist when the session is decoded elsewhere, PHP automatically transforms it to its original string type. However, `hey` is also a reference to `$foo`, but since the referenced variable is stored as `baz` now, PHP will encode `hey` as a reference to `baz`.

Comment: I'm confused by the value of the session encoded reference variables. Is it an index of $_SESSION?

Comment: @stevebot: It seems like an one-based index from $_SESSION, excluding references (which is why `hey` would have 2 instead of 3). If you change `bar` to a non-reference, `hey` reference number should become 3.

Answer (score 0):

Ahh, I think I see what it's doing.  Try doing something like this:

```
$array = array(array(1));
$array[1] =& $array[0];
```

So now, the array should look like:

```
array(
    0 => array(
        0 => 1
    ),
    1 => &array(
        0 => 1
    ),
)
```

That should trigger the reference type (with any luck).